# Dactyl-ManuForm vs Kinesis Advantage 360

Tags: keyboards, ergonomics

I am in the market for a split orthonormal ergonomic keyboard. I have an issue with my shoulder that gets worse when I type.

I bought an Ergodox EZ and while I thought it was a definite improvement I ended up returning it. After doing more research I learned that I should have gotten the modeled keycaps, but I got the backlit Ergodox EZ which doesn't support these keycaps and the molded keycaps on the Ergodox was a worse version of what the Dactyl-ManuForm and Kinesis Advantage 360 were delivering with their truly concaved form factors.

I am trying to determine which is the "best" ergonomic keyboard for me. I am leaning towards the Dactyl-ManuForm. But I don't have the time, means, or interest to build my own. I am looking at this option: https://taikohub.com/products/dactyl-manuform-keyboard-v2 but I am curious whether the 5 Keyed Thumb Cluster or the 6 Keyed Thumb Cluster is a better option. Also, I am currently in Los Angeles, does anyone know another option (around here or otherwise) for configuring and buying a prebuilt Dactyl-ManuForm?

It looks like the Kinesis Advantage 360 is another good option that delivers a similar form factor. Has anyone tried both and can they recommend one over the other?

Lastly, I really liked that the Ergodox EZ had the ORYX software which allowed you not only to configure the keyboard but also a series of training exercises. I am not a great touch typer but it is something I will need to get skilled with in order to properly use these keyboards (especially if I get a dactyl without markings on the keycaps, like the rebuilt one I linked). Is there an analogous software training tool for the Dactyl-ManuForm and/or Advantage 360?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

See [/u/carbonfet](https://www.reddit.com/u/carbonfet/) on Reddit.

He accepts commissions for custom builds, but also has some prebuilt Dactyls for sale [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/mechmarket/comments/zhaouc/caon_h_dactylmanuform_w_corsas_w_paypal/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/mechmarket/comments/w6ep7u/caon_h_dactylmanuform_w_tangerines_w_paypal/)!

A KA360 is certainly inferior to his builds, yet he charges 1/2 the price!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found this retailer as well. Any thoughts on these builds? https://www.cyboard.digital/product-page/Dactyl-Manuform